# 2dimensional array and getElementsByName

Tags: javascript

I am trying to recode a sudoku game to be used in smart tv's. I want to find empty cells that the puzzle didn't fill at the beginning. I declared a 2 dimensional aray

```
var emptyCellsArray =new Array(9);
    emptyCellsArray[0] = new Array();
    emptyCellsArray[1] = new Array();
    emptyCellsArray[2] = new Array();
    emptyCellsArray[3] = new Array();
    emptyCellsArray[4] = new Array();
    emptyCellsArray[5] = new Array();
    emptyCellsArray[6] = new Array();
    emptyCellsArray[7] = new Array();
    emptyCellsArray[8] = new Array();
```

write the function

```
function fillEmptyCellsArray() {
for ( var i= 1 ; i<=9; i++) {
for (var k=1 ; k<=9; k++) {
        emptyCellsArray[i][k] = 0;          
};   //k end
}; //i end  

for ( var i= 1 ; i<=9; i++) {
var flag = 0;
    for (var k=1 ; k<=9; k++) {
        if ( !(document.getElementsByName(i+'_'+k)[0].value == "" )  ) {
            //add this cell to the array
            emptyCellsArray[i][flag] = 1;
            flag++; 
        }  //end if 
    };   //k end
}; //i end

alert("XX------" + emptyCellsArray[0][0]  );

}; //function end
```

then called the function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    fillEmptyCellsArray();
});
```

but i am getting this error output.

Error Detail : TypeError: document.getElementsByName(i + "_" + k)[0] is undefined

coming from this line---> if ( !(document.getElementsByName(i+'_'+k)[0].value == "" )

I am not pro, i couldn't figure it out. What is my mistake? I think the problem is in the declaration part. Can anybody enlighten me?

second version now all array filled with 1's

```
function fillEmptyCellsArray() {
for ( var i=0 ; i<9; i++) {
    for (var k=0 ; k<9; k++) {
        emptyCellsArray[i][k] = 0;          
    };   //k end
}; //i end  

for ( var i= 0; i<9; i++) {
    for (var k=0 ; k<9; k++) {
        if ( !(document.getElementsByName(i+'_'+k)[0].value == "" )  ) {
            //add this cell to the array
            emptyCellsArray[i][k] = 1;
        }  //end if 
    };   //k end
}; //i end

for ( var i=0 ; i<9; i++) {
    for (var k=0 ; k<9; k++) {
        alert ( emptyCellsArray[i][k] );            
    };   //k end
}; //i end
```

}; //function end

Comment: i forgot to mention, i am trying to access these objects: 
<div id="one"><input name="0_0" onfocus="{currentG=0;currentP=0;}"   type="text" value="1"></div>

<div id="one"><input name="0_1" onfocus="{currentG=0;currentP=1;}"   type="text" value="2"></div>

Comment: Just a question. Will you ever reach `0_0` if you start with k=1 and i=1 ?

Comment: and since you should really be checking the array length BEFORE you actually try to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now your example names start at 0 and your loops start at 1. Do you have 9_9 element or is the last one 8_8.

I am guessing you really want your loops to look like this

```
for ( var i= 0 ; i<9; i++) {
    var flag = 0;
    for (var k=0 ; k<9; k++) {
```

Comment: Thank you,problem is practically solved but another problem arose all array turned into 1's. Is javascript this much fragile or am i the one who made all mistakes.